# How to make Thonny use Python3.9.5 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, thonny

I am running Windows 10. Python 3.9.5 is installed and works well.
However, when I install Thonny, I also get Python 3.7.9 installed by default.
How can I make Thonny use Python 3.9.5 instead of 3.7.9?

Answer (score 0):

You can select another interpreter by selecting "Run => Select interpreter => Alternative Python 3 ..." and locating the python.exe of your Python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

In Thonny 3.3.13, you can specify another version of Python you want to use in Tools > Options : Interpreter tab.